# Is it possible to only use the vSphere client without vCenter?

Tags: vmware

If i would like to manage either a single ESXi host or multiple ESXi hosts, is it mandatory to have vCenter or can i limit management to the vSphere client?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. I've been managing my single esxi host with just vSphere client.

Comment: @Frank Thomas - Can you elaborate on what you mean as i'm new to the VMWare suite of products?

Comment: I too am new to esxi, but as i understand it, you need vCenter to do stuff like vMotioning guests between servers automatically, etc. as far as setting up the host, building VMs, and monitoring, I have gotten most of what I need from vSphere client. I have had to ssh in to do a few things though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the vSphere client to connect to and manage your hosts directly. Note that you can't manage features such as HA, DRS or FT directly. For those you need to connect to a vCenter Server.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean that vCenter is not needed to manage a single or multiple hosts?

Comment: vCenter isn't a requirement to manage individual hosts. If you want to create a cluster with those hosts and use features like HA, DRS or FT or if you want to manage the hosts as a single "entity" then you will need vCenter.